# How to customer data in value antd and Put axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, antd

### How to customer data in value antd and Put axios

https://ant.design/components/form/
[image]
The input does not let me change the data that will be updated by axios
I must still be able to fix it.
I want to show Antd form data. I read the review and use initialValues But I still can't.

```
componentDidMount () {
  let id = this.props.match.params.id;
  httpClient
      .get(`http://localhost:8085/api/v1/customer/customer/${id}`)
      .then((e) => this.setState({ 
            cus_fname: e.data.cus_fname,
            cus_lname: e.data.cus_lname,
            cus_email: e.data.cus_email,
            cus_tel: e.data.cus_tel,
            cus_car_number: e.data.cus_car_number,
            cus_band: e.data.cus_band,
            cus_address: e.data.cus_address,
       }));
}
  onFinish = async(values) => {
    // console.log("ค่า values ที่มาจาก form: ", values);
    const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("cus_fname", values.cus_fname);
      formData.append("cus_lname", values.cus_lname);
      formData.append("cus_email", values.cus_email);
      formData.append("cus_tel", values.cus_tel);
      formData.append("cus_car_number", values.cus_car_number);
      formData.append("cus_band", values.cus_band);
      formData.append("cus_address", values.cus_address);
    await httpClient
      .put(`http://localhost:8085/api/v1/customer/customer/`, formData )
      .then((res) => {
        // console.log(res.data);
        // console.log( "PushData to server success : ", res);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error :", error);
      });
    await this.props.history.goBack();
  };

  handleChange = event => {
    event.persist();
    this.setState({
      [event.target.fname]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
      const { fname, lname, email, phone, band, cus_address, car_number} = this.state;
   return (
         <Form {...layout} name="nest-messages" onFinish{this.updateCustomer}  >
                  <FormItem
                    label="ชื่อ"
                    name="fname"
                    defaultValue={fname} 
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: "โปรดระบุชื่อ ", }]}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                  > 
                    <Input  />
                  </FormItem>



)
```

Comment: can you share your this.handleChange function ?

Comment: handleChange = event => {
    event.persist();
    this.setState({
      [event.target.fname]: event.target.value,
      [event.target.lname]: event.target.value,
      [event.target.email]: event.target.value,
      [event.target.phone]: event.target.value,
      [event.target.car_number]: event.target.value,
      [event.target.band]: event.target.value,
      [event.target.cus_address]: event.target.value,
    })
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initialValues will show only the state value on the first render, it will not change the value of the form on componentDidMount even you did setState because that will be a second render.. to achieve it you need a reference to the form and use the [api](https://ant.design/components/form/#FormInstance) of the instance.

```
//create instance
formRef = React.createRef();

componentDidMount () {    
    let id = this.props.match.params.id;
    httpClient
        .get(`http://localhost:8085/api/v1/customer/customer/${id}`)
        .then((e) => {

            this.formRef.current.setFieldsValue({
                cus_fname: e.data.cus_fname,
                cus_lname: e.data.cus_lname,
                cus_email: e.data.cus_email,
                cus_tel: e.data.cus_tel,
                cus_car_number: e.data.cus_car_number,
                cus_band: e.data.cus_band,
                cus_address: e.data.cus_address,
            });

            //you can still do a setState
            /*this.setState({ 
                cus_fname: e.data.cus_fname,
                cus_lname: e.data.cus_lname,
                cus_email: e.data.cus_email,
                cus_tel: e.data.cus_tel,
                cus_car_number: e.data.cus_car_number,
                cus_band: e.data.cus_band,
                cus_address: e.data.cus_address,
           });*/
        })
  }
```

and in the Form component:

```
  <Form  ref={this.formRef} {...layout} name="nest-messages" onFinish={this.updateCustomer} >
      ...
  </Form>
```

take note that there is no onChange callback on <Form.Item> component on antd documentation. If you want to change the state on every change, use onValuesChange props of the Form.

```
<Form onValuesChange={(changedValues, allValues) => {
      /* perform setState */
}}>
</Form>
```

You may also want to look on this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/btmyq?file=/index.js:863-881) for more info.